# How to make a mixin helper responsive using breakpoints?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to make this mixin responsive means it generate the media queries
based on **breakpoints**.

**Here is my SCSS Code :**

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1400px
) !default;

    @mixin overscroll-behavior-auto() {
      -ms-scroll-chaining: chained;
          overscroll-behavior: auto;
    }
    @mixin overscroll-behavior-contain() {
      -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
          overscroll-behavior: contain;
    }
    @mixin overscroll-behavior-none() {
      -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
          overscroll-behavior: none;
    }
    .overscroll-auto {
        @include overscroll-behavior-auto();
    }
    .overscroll-contain {
        @include overscroll-behavior-contain();
    }
    .overscroll-none {
        @include overscroll-behavior-none();
    }

    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {}
    }
```

I include my sass code thank you guys

Comment: Hey, could you include your breakpoints too?

Comment: yeah I update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/xxOZVqW?editors=1112)

I made some modifications to the syntax of `overscroll-behavior()`. Mainly that its not `overscroll-behavior-auto()`, `overscroll-behavior-contain()` etc. any longer, but:

```
overscroll-behavior($behavior, $breakpoint);
```

This was necessary to not write the same code three times, since you can't generate `mixins`.

```
$overscrollBehavior: (
  "auto":    ["chained", "none"   ],
  "contain": ["none",    "contain"],
  "none":    ["none",    "none"   ],
)!default;

$breakpoints: (
  "xs":  0px,
  "sm":  576px,
  "md":  768px,
  "lg":  992px,
  "xl":  1200px,
  "xxl": 1400px,
) !default;


@mixin overscroll-behavior($behavior, $breakpoint) {
  $map: $overscrollBehavior;
  
  @for $i from 1 through length($map) {
    $label: nth(nth($map, $i), 1);
    $values: nth(nth($map, $i), 2);
    
    @if $behavior == $label {
      $map: $breakpoints;
      
      @for $i from 1 through length($map) {
        $bp: nth(nth($map, $i), 1);
        $bpValue: nth(nth($map, $i), 2);
        
        @if $breakpoint == $bp {
          @media (min-width: #{$bpValue}) {
            -ms-scroll-chaining: unquote(nth($values, 1));
            overscroll-behavior: unquote(nth($values, 2));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
body {
  @include overscroll-behavior(none, xs);
}
```

```
@media (min-width: 0px) {
  body {
    -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
  }
}
```

If that's not quite what your looking for, let me know!

Comment: thank you so mush my friend for your help you are the best